# can Jtable has focus as a whole?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

So in my code, I had

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.requestFocus();
table.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("Table Focus gained !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    });
```

But when I test the code, the table doesn't have focus.

So can a `JTable` as a whole have focus or only a cell of table can have focus?
Extend the question above, can `JTable` as a whole has a `KeyListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you are trying to focus the table so the key listener will work. I'd say don't use a KeyListener at all. Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, where you have more control over the actions in different focus contexts. See the link for more explanation.

A simple example is if you add a key bind to the `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` input map, the component doesn't have to be focused in order for the keys to work.  On the other hand, if you only want the keys to work then the table is focused, you can use the `WHEN_FOCUSED` input map, in which case you need to `requestFocusInWindow` on the table *after* the main frame/window that the contains the table is visible.

Here's a simple example of the first `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. (Type ctrl+shift+space)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[][] data = {{"Data"}};
                String[] cols = {"COlo"};
                JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);

                int focusCondition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
                String name = "random";
                String key = "ctrl shift SPACE";
                addKeyBinding(table, name, key, focusCondition);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void addKeyBinding(JComponent component,
            final String name,
            final String key,
            int focusCondition) {
        InputMap iMap = component.getInputMap(focusCondition);
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), name);
        ActionMap aMap = component.getActionMap();
        aMap.put(name, new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + key + " pressed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: so can jtable as a whole has focus?

Comment: Yes. `jTable.isFocusable() == true`. You just need to request focus to it programmatically or  by clicking it or tabbing to it